# PhpStorm xdebug configuration for php

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

After installing Xdebug on Windows 10 and test that with `php --version` command I get this output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\instacheeta>php --version
PHP 7.2.4 (cli) (built: Mar 28 2018 04:46:46) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.0alpha1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

After that I enable `debug` mode in PhpStorm by clicking on: [image] , enabling Firefox `XDebug` addons: [image] and then make break point on PhpStorm I expect that work correctly and stop on my break points.

[image]

But there are one problem, when I opening `Validate debugger configuration` dialog I can't validate debugger configuration

[image]
[image]
[image]

UPDTAE:

[image]
[image]

My web app work on `8000` port with `http://127.0.0.1` IP and my web app folder is in `C:\xampp\htdocs\instacheeta` path

Comment: check the mapping in settings->language&framework->PHP->servers to be set

Comment: @Edwin after that and adding server i have problem too

Comment: @Edwin i added some other screenshots to my post, how about Xdebug port?

Comment: absoulte path on server should be your entrypoint let's say index.php or whatever you have. And I usually have 9000 for the xdebugger as port.

Comment: @Edwin are you familiar with laravel?

Comment: If you did not manually specify xdebug.remote_port in your php.ini, it should be 9000 in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug. see https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_port

Comment: @VladLuchansky i chenge that to 9000, whats this problem? `File path is not mapped to any file path on server. Edit path mappings to fix the problem.`

Comment: You need to go to File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers and set the path mappings between the remote server and your local project. Try to set a correct absolute path for the project directory so PhpStorm would connect data coming from Xdebug with a correct file.

Comment: @VladLuchansky i change that and resolve problem, but debugger don't worked again

Comment: Are there any errors? How does it behave at the moment?

Comment: @VladLuchansky i dont get any error, but debugger don't stop on my break points

Comment: What if you enable Run | Break at first line in PHP scripts? Will it stop anywhere?

Comment: @VladLuchansky no, couldn't stop on break points :( do you have AnyDesk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM RESOLVE

i cahnged `xdebug` setting into `php.ini` to:

```
zend_extension=xdebug
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable =1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

and adding `PHPSTORM` IDE key on PHPStorm settings from `settings->PHP->Debug->DBGP`

[image]